# TCL write and read only one value

Tags: tcl

Hi guys I am using TCL  (IVR/TCL) for Cisco Voice Gateway.. and I need to have a text file that inside only have a OPEN or CLOSED value.. just 1 value.. so when a call arrieves I check if the business is open or closed..

Then I make another TCL just to the manager place a call and open/close the bussiness..

I have read that you could use a temp file to before writing the file... Is that really necesary

Basically what I just need is take the first line and write OPEN or CLOSED  and then in the other tcl just read the file and read the value..

What I must have in mind is take care that the file has only one line... and on closed or open value set..

```
 for reading I am using 
set fd [open $filename]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
       set data [lindex $line 0]
       puts "\n  Date: $data ::"

       if { [expr { $data == "closed" }] } {
                 set closed "1"
                 puts "\n Date Found on the List"
}
```

But is really necessary couse I am just reading one line ??
How could I write the file...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that the line of interest is always the first one, it's easy. For one thing, there's no real need to use looping or to try to split the line into words; a simple glob-match with `string match` (which returns a boolean) is quite enough.

```
# Reader
set fd [open $filename]
set closed [string match "closed*" [gets $fd]]
close $fd
```

```
# Writer
set fd [open $filename w]
if {$closed} {
    puts $fd "closed"
} else {
    puts $fd "open"
}
close $fd
```

And that's all that's really required (except for the rest of the logic to turn the fragments into a whole program, of course) though you can also do things like also writing the date of the change. (Of course, that would also be preserved in the file's metadata… but it's an illustration, OK?)

```
set timestamp [clock format [clock seconds]]
if {$closed} {
    puts $fd "closed - $timestamp"
} else {
    puts $fd "open - $timestamp"
}
```

And so on.